# Where can I obtain an Eclipse server adapter for WebSphere Application Server Version 7?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, eclipse-wtp

I need to set up an Eclipse WTP project pointing to a WAS V7 instance but I can't find the server adapter to work with version 7. Version 6 is supported.

Comment: [This is the new link.](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v70-developer-tools-eclipse-36-only)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this answer comes late in the day, but it is put down to help others understand how WTP support for WebSphere works in Eclipse.

WTP support for the newer versions of the WebSphere Application Server come only with commercial IDEs - Rational Application Developer, for example. MyEclipse is another IDE that comes with support for WAS 7; one would need the Blue Edition to work against a v7.0 WAS instance.

The philosophy is that if the vanilla Eclipse WTP project has to support an application server, then the application server vendor must either provide the adapter or some means to perform the integration. For obvious reasons, this is absent for WAS 6.1 and 7.0, but available for 6.0.

This was the case, but IBM has since release WebSphere Application Server tools edition and has donated a server adapter to the Eclipse market place.  This will cover WAS 7, 8 and 8.5 alpha.

- [Overview](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/beta/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.w4d.nd.multiplatform.doc/topics/wdtV85_overview.html)
- [Eclipse 3.6 plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v70-developer-tools-eclipse-36-only)
- [Liberty profile (8.5 alpha)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/websphere-application-server-developer-tools-liberty-profile-eclipse-37)

Comment: What 'obvious reasons'?  That IBM requires has legal standing to only allow 'commercial ides' to integrate?

Comment: @Eric, nope. IBM donated the code for the WAS 6.0 adapter, but hasn't for 6.1 and 7. Therefore, external contributions would be required to get adapters for other servers.

Comment: Ahh, the obvious reason being anti-competitive behavior by IBM.  'We need to be allowed to continue to sell expensive and inferior IDEs'

Comment: I am not able to find the pages for the links posted in answers. Seems like the WAS 6.1 adapter for Eclipse has been moved or removed. regards,
Mohit.

Answer (score 9):

This was the case, but IBM has since release WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools and has donated a server adapter to the Eclipse market place. This covers WAS 7, 8 and 8.5 alpha.

Overview: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Developer Tools are available via Eclipse marketplace. I am using it right now with WAS 8.5 and Eclipse version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
[image]