# Eclipse development environment for WAS 6.1

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-6.1

Currently I am working with MyEclipse for developing a J2EE application for WAS 6.1.

I noticed that eclipse added the new J2EE development environment.
When trying to configure it I can see that there is a support for WebSphere 6.0 only.

Is it possible to configure the environment to work / debug with WAS 6.1/7.0?

Any cookbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this message on the Eclipse Community Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=60521&S=116fb0952cbb1a05af7bfd551b0f840b) from July 2009:

> In speaking with IBM representatives
> for our company, I have been told that
> the WebSphere/WTP
> performance/integration issues [1] and
> WAS 6.1 support [2] are currently
> being addressed and should be
> contributed back to WTP with the
> release of RAD 7. These bugs are still
> in NEW status. Is there any work being
> done on these bugs? What is the
> expected target milestone?
>
> [1]: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=163218
> [2]: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=160220

You can read [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331535/where-can-i-obtain-an-eclipse-server-adapter-for-websphere-application-server-ver) too to understand why this takes so much time (gotta love IBM). So for now, without RAD7 (funnily, I personally find that RAD sucks like hell) or another commercial tool like MyEclipse, you'll need to attach manually to port 7781 of a running WebSphere server that was started in debug mode outside of the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I know when using rational which is the eclipse based idea for WAS you have to install the websphere components for the relative versions. With rational this is done through the ibm installation manager.

I am guessing you are missing the relative plugin , sorry cannot be more help

karl