# where I can download Websphere Application Server 7 (was 7) server adapter for springsource tools

Tags: websphere, springsource

like the title...

I want to find was7 server adapter for springsource toos.

any body know where I must download the software ??? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you still can't get it for free, you have to get a commercial IDE (RAD, MyEclipse) for that. See this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331535/where-can-i-obtain-an-eclipse-server-adapter-for-websphere-application-server-ver) and this more [recent discussion](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=165140&).

Answer (score 1):

This was the case, but IBM has since release WebSphere Application Server tools edition and has donated a server adapter to the Eclipse market place. This will cover WAS 7, 8 and 8.5 alpha.

Overview http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/beta/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.w4d.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Ftopics%2FwdtV85_overview.html

Current Eclipse plugin alpha http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/websphere-application-server-developer-tools-eclipse