# RSA 8.5.1 doesn't let me to publish my web app on Websphere 6.1

Tags: ejb, websphere, websphere-6.1, rational-rsa

My problem is related to the publish of a web app in RSA 8.5.1 using WebSphere 6.1. The web app is developed in Struts 1 with Spring 3.0. Before this problem, I was developing in RAD 7.0 (using the same version of WebSphere) without problems.

But when I had to migrate to RSA 8.5.1, and after configure all JNDI references, jdbc connections and resources locations, when I start WebSphere, and after deploy the web app, WebSphere doesn't let me to publish the web app.

The message appears in a popup and it tells me something like WebSphere (6.1) supports EJB 3.0 and that I have to install those features both WebSpehere and my app.

This wouldn't be a problem if was a private app, but it wasn't. I have to ask persmissions for local admin on the pc if I want to install the fix.

Moreover, I am worried if the webapp could be affected by this additional feature.

So, is there any possibilities to tell RSA 8.5.1 or WebSphere 6.1 that I DO NOT WANT this feature and it let me to publish my web app normally? I',m in a rush and I have to continue working.

I have been googlin' for 1 day without any correct answer.

Sincerely, I don't know why IBM oblies to us to install theirs fixes if we don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it makes sense that you need an specific feature that your RAD does not have. You should have someone from Architecture that can address this issue for you. If you don't, try to work around with File -> Export then try to deploy it from the EAR and see what error appears.

Conclusion: Workaround your RAD.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support by IBM for WAS 6.1 in RSA 8.5. If you want full integration between RSA and WAS 6.1 you need to use an earlier version of RSA. This lack of support also means that there are no WAS 6.1 server adapters included with RSA 8.5 and that is why deployment is not running as you would hope.

Unless you are restricted due to other reasons IBM licensing is usually not limited to a specific version and there should not be any reason why you could not run two different major versions of RSA on the same machine.

It is possible to develop your web application in RSA 8.5+ and use it in a WAS 6.1 server but it will not work with integrated deployment in RSA 8.5.

More about RSA/WAS 6.1 combo in this answer: [Is it possible to run Websphere Application Server 6.1 Test environment in Rational Software Architect (RSA) version 9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093113/is-it-possible-to-run-websphere-application-server-6-1-test-environment-in-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all replies...

finally my problem was the version of the EAR, which was EAR 5.0 (due to use an extension of WAS 6.1).

All I had to do is to downgrade the EAR to 1.4 version and the warning messages from WAS dissapeared.

I am very pleased for your interest and your answers, and I hope this entry will be useful in the near future.

Best Regards!!!!!